# How to find a method that matches declaration rules?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I need to find methods that match certain rules such as

- has to be have return type void
- has to be named "Set"
- has to accept only one parameter
- parameter type needs to match the type provided

I started going down the following route, but is just seems too much code. I wonder if there is a better way?

```
//find type name of the property
foreach (var propertySymbol in propertiesSymbols)
{

    var propertyTypeSyntax =
        ((PropertyDeclarationSyntax) propertySymbol.DeclaringSyntaxNodes.First()).Type;

    var propertyTypeInfo = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(propertyTypeSyntax);

    //find method with a name Set that accepts this type of the property
    var allSetMethodsSymbols = classSymbol.GetMembers()
                               .Where(m => m.Kind == CommonSymbolKind.Method && m.Name.Equals("Set"))
                               .ToList();

    foreach (var setMethodSymbol in allSetMethodsSymbols)
    {

        var methodDeclarationSyntax =
            ((MethodDeclarationSyntax) setMethodSymbol.DeclaringSyntaxNodes.First());

        var expressionSyntax =
            methodDeclarationSyntax.DescendantNodes().OfType<ExpressionSyntax>().First();

        var typeInfo = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(expressionSyntax);

        var typeName = typeInfo.Type.Name;

        if (typeName == "Void")
        {
            //now we know it is a method named "Set" and has return type "Void"

            //let's see if parameter matches
            var parameterSymbols =
                methodDeclarationSyntax.DescendantNodes().OfType<ParameterSyntax>()
                                    .ToList();

            if (parameterSymbols.Count() == 1)
            {
                //this one has one parameter
                //now let's see if it is of the type needed
                var exprSyntax = ((ParameterSyntax) parameterSymbols.First())
                                            .DescendantNodes().OfType<ExpressionSyntax>().First();

                var parameterTypeInfo = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(exprSyntax);

                if (parameterTypeInfo.Type.Equals(propertyTypeInfo.Type))
                {
                    //execute method rewriter
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Solution as suggested by Jason:

```
var propertyTypeInfo = propertySymbol.Type;

//find method with a name Set that accepts this type of the property
IEnumerable<MethodSymbol> allSetMethodsSymbols = classSymbol
                                                .GetMembers()
                                                .Where(m =>m.Kind == CommonSymbolKind.Method && m.Name.Equals("Set"))
                                                .Cast<MethodSymbol>();

var setMethod = allSetMethodsSymbols
    .Single(x => x.ReturnsVoid
                && x.Parameters.Count == 1
                && x.Parameters.First().Type == propertyTypeInfo);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're switching back and forth between our symbol model and syntax, which is making this more difficult than it needs to be. Cast those symbol objects you are getting from GetMembers to MethodSymbol (once checking that they're a method). Once you've got the MethodSymbol, you can just check the .ReturnType property to get the return type -- don't go to syntax and re-get it that way. Or, just use the handy .ReturnsVoid property for your scenario. Similarly, MethodSymbol has a .Parameters property you can use to get the parameters -- don't go back to syntax for that either.